# JavaFX: Why doesn't my MinMax algorithm make a move when it starts a TicTacToe game?

Tags: java, javafx, tic-tac-toe, mouseclick-event, onmouseclick

I have a working MinMax algorithm, tested in other situations, the JavaFX implementation doesn't work when the computer (MinMax) has to make the first move, I have to click first.

There is a bug in the code, because when the computer (player2) starts, it doesn't want to make a move first, then when I click for it, then the game goes on normally and the algorithm works correctly, when I start as player1 it's ok.

```
        pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (currentPlayer.equals(player1)) {
                if (label.getText().isEmpty() && !isEndOfGame) {
                    label.setText(currentPlayer.getSymbol());
                    changePlayerTurn();
                    verifyResultOfTheDuel();

                    if (mode.equals(SINGLE_PLAYER) && !isEndOfGame && currentPlayer.equals(player2)) {
                        makeComputerMove(difficulty);
                        changePlayerTurn();
                        verifyResultOfTheDuel();
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentPlayer.equals(player2)) {
                if (label.getText().isEmpty() && !isEndOfGame) {
                    if (mode.equals(SINGLE_PLAYER)) {
                        makeComputerMove(difficulty);
                        changePlayerTurn();
                        verifyResultOfTheDuel();
                    } else if (mode.equals(MULTI_PLAYER)) {
                        label.setText(currentPlayer.getSymbol());
                        changePlayerTurn();
                        verifyResultOfTheDuel();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. In your case, you have to click first because the code within your `OnMouseClicked` event is only executed when `pane` is clicked.

In order for the "computer" to make its move when it starts, you should make the check outside of the `OnMouseClicked` event.